# Send a cached JSON string as JSON

Tags: javascript, json, express, ecmascript-6, send

In an express 5.5.1, app. I have a validated 1.79MB json string cached as a global variable that we will called **strJSON** in this post.

I want to send this string to the client **without express modifying it** and I want the header to be:

```
('Content-Type', 'application/json')
```

This doesn't work:

```
res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
res.send(strJSON);
```

Express modifies the string by encapsulating it in quotes and putting backslashes before every quote in the JSON.

This produces the same result:

```
res.json(strJSON);
```

This sends the string unmodified:

```
res.send(strJSON);
```

However, the client sees this wrong content-type:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

I do not want to waste processing time converting this valid JSON string to an object in order for res.send to indicate the proper content type. The whole point of caching this json string to a global variable is so that it can be sent from RAM as quickly as possible (requiring the least amount of prep-work by express).

How can I send this string unmodified as application/json?

Comment: `res.send(JSON.parse(strJSON));` or better keep strJSON already as an object

Comment: @nam8er: Thanks, but please read the paragraph preceding my question (at the end of my post).

Comment: @LonnieBest I think if it's super necessary to be performant You may just put in some file and serve it using web server (nginx)

Comment: try this: `res.type('json').end(strJSON);`

Comment: Great suggestion; ***res.type('json').send(strJSON)*** worked, but I'm not seeing much of a performance gain. Seems like it is probably equivalent to caching an object and sending it with res.send(). I was hoping to send this in a way where the string doesn't have to be verified as json or converted to an object before sending it as json. All that work was done before it was cached, and I don't want it to be done again.

Comment: maybe making Buffer from it and sending buffer may help. But I think it's already doing it automatically. So as I said try to put that data to data.json and serve it from nginx

Comment: Also attach `compression` middleware to make network output smaller

Comment: I hear you. I'm currently comparing express's performance to a cached file. Express is taking about 20ms longer than the cached file, because express refuses not to do prep-work before just sending the json from RAM. Otherwise, I think it would be just as fast or faster.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171825/discussion-between-lonnie-best-and-num8er).

Comment: After further testing, I think ***res.type('json').send(strJSON)*** did help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't because if it didn't add the backslashes to the quotes it wouldn't be a valid JSON.